# How to add Check constraints to the database?

Tags: sql-server-2014

I want to add the following check constraints to the table named "service", to the column "status"

```
CREATE TABLE Service(
Service_ID INT(5) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
Invoice_ID INT(5),
Project_ID INT(5) NOT NULL,
Description CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Start_Date VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
Due_Date VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
Planned_Price VARCHAR (10),
Actual_Price VARCHAR (10),
Status CHAR (10) NOT NULL,
Date_Completed VARCHAR (10)
);
```

The content/sample data of "status" column will be 1 from the following.
 planned, active, completed

*if active or completed: DueDate, StartDate and PlannedPrice are all not null
* if completed: DateCompleted and ActualPrice are both not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test it,
however this is the first one

```
ALTER TABLE Service WITH NOCHECK  
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_serice_one 
CHECK (
    (Status IN ('active','completed')
          AND DueDate IS NOT NULL
          AND StartDate IS NOT NULL
          AND PlannedPrice IS NOT NULL)
    OR Status NOT IN ('active','completed')
);
```

and this is the second

```
ALTER TABLE Service WITH NOCHECK  
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_serice_two
CHECK (
    (Status LIKE 'completed'
          AND DateCompleted IS NOT NULL
          AND ActualPrice IS NOT NULL)
    OR Status NOT LIKE 'completed'
);
```

Comment: Thankyou, it really helped. Do i execute both these constraints in independant alter table staements or do i have to execute them in one alter table statement

Comment: like independant is ok,

Answer (score 0):

This helps

```
Status CHAR(10) NOT NULL CHECK (Status IN ('planned', 'active', 'completed'))

(Status like 'active' and DueDate NOT NULL AND StartDate not NULL)
```